# iOS - MPMediaPickerController - Show only Playlists

Tags: ios, mpmediapickercontroller

Using MPMediaPickerController, can we just show only one tab, that is "Play lists" in the app? 
My requirement is just to show the play lists and on tapping the play list songs has to be played.

I tried using MPMediaQuery, but I'm not just getting the play lists, but all the songs in the play lists are returned.
Is there any other solution to get only play lists?